# using str_replace to replace anything inside a link text (anchor text)

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, categories, str-replace

I am using str_replace to replace anything inside a link text (anchor text).

I want to replace the word 'SMS' from the anchor text inside a wordpress category name,

```
<?php echo str_replace("SMS","",(the_category(', '))) ; ?>
```

but it doesn't work.  It does work for a replacement of normal string,

```
$txt = "Sufyan"
    <?php echo str_replace("S","a",$txt) ; ?>
```

The above code works but it doesn't work when I want to replace something from anchor text.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump(the_category(', '));`?

Comment: `the_category(', ')` does not return any values only prints them

Comment: it doesn't replace 'SMS' however it add a word 'Null' with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_category()` is a template tag with echos its results without returning them. Basic rule of thumb: if it starts with '`the_`' it echos without returning.

Change that line to

```
<?php echo str_replace("SMS","",(get_the_category_list(', '))) ; ?>
```

and `str_replace()` should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong method instead of [`get_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) use [`get_the_category_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list)